# How do I format the values of an array of `unsigned char` in hexadecimal?

Tags: c++

I have an array of unsigned char which contains hex values. I would like to show it in the logs and in order to do it I need to convert it into a string.

Obviously if I directly try to use the character array as a string I get gibberish as is it interpreted as ASCII (e.g., it will be rendered as: "\xfê)Z+’\x2". Ideally I want to show the raw hex values without them being interpreted.

I have tried to copy it into a string but have not been successful. I am going to present what I have tried and the results that I got:

```
//My starting data type is unsigned char *

unsigned char* index = Block_data.Index;

//I convert it to const char* since most functions I could find for this type of
//conversion require a const char *, if this step can be avoided: I will do that

const char* indexc1 = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(index);

char outVal[9]; //allocate target buffer space

sprintf_s(outVal, "%9x", indexc1); //copy to target. This manages to copy the 
                                 // address of indexc1 and not its contents
sprintf_s(outVal, "%9x", *indexc1); //This gets one character from the 
                                  // address

sscanf_s(indexc1, "%9x", outVal); //This gets empty string
```

I feel that the answer may be quite simple but after some research I tried the above and have not been successful. Since I am running out of ideas (I tried few similar things as above) I am turning to the community for some help on this.

Comment: Have you tried using the `to_string()` method?

Comment: Do you mean you have an array of characters which contain some unprintable characters? (When you say “hex values”, it is not clear what you mean. Values are numbers—they are abstract mathematical entities. Hexadecimal is a way of representing numbers using digits.) And you want to print the characters in the array, but print the unprintable ones in a format like “\x02” if its value is 2? Do you want to print all the values using hexadecimal or just the unprintable ones? E.g., should “A” be printed as “A” or “\x41”?

Comment: Assuming I have figured out something along the lines of what you want, I am not aware of a standard function for this. You should probably write a loop to print the array. In each iteration, print one character. Use `isprint` to determine if it is printable or not. If it is, print the character itself. If it is not, print it using hexadecimal formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I want to print the contents as raw hex. I can add an example beyond what I have (so for example I can add the example of hex characters and how they show up when interpreted as ascii).

Comment: Suppose the array were `unsigned char x[] = { 2, 65, 49, 255 };`, where 2 is not a printable character, 65 is “A”, 49 is “1”, and 255 is not a printable character. What do you want the result to be? Do you want it to be “\x02\x41\x31\xff”, “\x02A1\xff”, or something else? If something else, what?

Comment: `%9x` means *minimum of 9 characters + null terminator*, so you guarantee a buffer overflow.  I would suggest `snprintf` and a larger buffer (and make the argument match the format specifier)

Comment: @ Jake Freeman: std::to_string() seems to take only numeric arguments. I have an unsigned char * as the original data type.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: Thanks, I want to see just the raw hex treating it just as an internal hex index: so in this example it will be: 24131ff

Comment: I edited the title to clarify it, but I cannot clarify the body of the question without removing most of it. Really, your question is quite simple; “Given an array of `unsigned char`, how do I create a string containing each character’s value formatted in hexadecimal? For example, an array containing 2, 65, 48, 255 should produce the string “024131ff”.” For future readers, you might consider simplifying the question.

Comment: Shivesh, just a suggestion: although you can *use* the legacy C stuff in C++ (like printf), you'll never be considered a *serious* C++ developer until you embrace the C++ way of doing things. At best, you'll be considered what I refer to as a C+ programmer :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks. I will keep that in mind. I have mainly worked with C# and some C. In this case I was looking to get the results quickly as this is a project which depends on a C library. Part of the code base is native C++, some of it is CLI and rest is C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I am assuming you want to build a string showing , in hex, the values of the first four bytes pointed to by `index`.

The code could be:

```
char outVal[9];
sprintf(outVal, "%02X%02X%02X%02X", index[0], index[1], index[2], index[3]);
```

Do not try this with `char *` pointer, that could lead to undefined behaviour. It relies on `index` being `unsigned char *`.

If you want to print many more bytes, then you can switch to a loop, for example:

```
std::vector<char> outVal( 2 * len + 1 );
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    sprintf(&outVal[i * 2], "%02X", index[i]);

// OutputDebugString(&outVal[0]);
```

Comment: I tried sprintf(outVal, "%02X%02X%02X%02X", index[0], index[1], index[2], index[3]); and this seems to be giving me what I want!

Comment: @shiveshsuman no it is not. The `_s` functions are equal or worse security than the original versions.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have arbitrary characters that you want represented as hex, you can simply use `makeString()` and `appendChar()` from the following complete test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

// Append a single character as two-digit hex string.

void appendChar(std::stringstream &ss, const char *pref, const char ch) {
    ss  << pref
        << std::setfill('0')
        << std::setw(2)
        << std::hex
        << static_cast<unsigned int>(ch & 0xff);
}

// Construct a hex string from buffer.

std::string makeString(const char * const buff, size_t slen = 0) {
    std::stringstream ss;

    // Zero-length means C-style string.

    if (slen == 0)
        slen = strlen(buff);

    // Process each byte in character array.

    if (slen > 0) {
        appendChar(ss, "", buff[0]);
        for (size_t i = 1; i < slen; ++i)
            appendChar(ss, " ", buff[i]);
    }
    return ss.str();
}

// Rudimentary test code.

int main() {
    std::cout << makeString("hello", 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << makeString("\x3\x1\x4\x1\x5\x9\xff") << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not that hard to do that on a higher level (if this isn't a performance intensive application):

```
std::string hexToString(unsigned char c)
{
    std::string res = "";
    if (c >= 0xF0)
    {
        res += "F";
        c -= 0xF0;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xE0)
    {
        res += "E";
        c -= 0xE0;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xD0)
    {
        res += "D";
        c -= 0xD0;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xC0)
    {
        res += "C";
        c -= 0xC0;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xB0)
    {
        res += "B";
        c -= 0xB0;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xA0)
    {
        res += "A";
        c -= 0xA0;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x90)
    {
        res += "9";
        c -= 0x90;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x80)
    {
        res += "8";
        c -= 0x80;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x70)
    {
        res += "7";
        c -= 0x70;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x60)
    {
        res += "6";
        c -= 0x60;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x50)
    {
        res += "5";
        c -= 0x50;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x40)
    {
        res += "4";
        c -= 0x40;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x30)
    {
        res += "3";
        c -= 0x30;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x20)
    {
        res += "2";
        c -= 0x20;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x10)
    {
        res += "1";
        c -= 0x10;
    }
    else
    {
        res += "0";
    }


    if (c >= 0xF)
    {
        res += "F";
        c -= 0xF;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xE)
    {
        res += "E";
        c -= 0xE;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xD)
    {
        res += "D";
        c -= 0xD;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xC)
    {
        res += "C";
        c -= 0xC;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xB)
    {
        res += "B";
        c -= 0xB;
    }
    else if (c >= 0xA)
    {
        res += "A";
        c -= 0xA0;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x9)
    {
        res += "9";
        c -= 0x90;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x8)
    {
        res += "8";
        c -= 0x8;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x7)
    {
        res += "7";
        c -= 0x7;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x6)
    {
        res += "6";
        c -= 0x6;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x5)
    {
        res += "5";
        c -= 0x5;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x4)
    {
        res += "4";
        c -= 0x4;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x3)
    {
        res += "3";
        c -= 0x3;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x2)
    {
        res += "2";
        c -= 0x2;
    }
    else if (c >= 0x1)
    {
        res += "1";
        c -= 0x10;
    }
    else res += "0";
    return res;
}
```

This is like a rather hacked interpretation, but it's quite reliable.